# I'm trying to create a Notification System without websockets & polling - Just simple JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, notifications

I'm trying to build a real-time notification system without the use of Websockets or Polling, in the most efficient and fastest manner with no lags, and which costs the least UX.

This is the idea I drafted so far:

1- Each time  a user (A) receives a message from another user (B), I use PHP to convey the messages between user A and B, and MySQL to store the transaction with a timestamp.

2- I run a Cronjob every 60 seconds to parse the MySQL data into JSON format, and update a file called `data.JSON` which stores all the messages between all the users on my website (@ stackoverflow security folks, there won't be any sensitive data or personal messages in the notifications if you're going to arrest me for that!). This means that the file is updated every 60 seconds whether there is new data to fetch or not.
And this is an example the output in JSON format:

```
[
{
  "notification": {
      "user_ref": "00007939786",
      "sender": "12089301923",
      "message": "Message 1",
      "created_at": "2019-02-11 14:47:11"
  }
}, 
{
  "notification": {
      "user_ref": "00007939786",
      "sender": "78921739812",
      "message": "Message 2",
      "created_at": "2019-02-11 14:46:11"
  }
},
{
  "notification": {
      "user_ref": "00007939787",
      "sender": "91290381920",
      "message": "Message 3",
      "created_at": "2019-02-11 14:34:11"
  }
},
...
```

3- The webpage (eg. index.html) also has a JavaScript setInterval function which checks for changes in the JSON file every 60 seconds (the same amount of seconds as the Cronjob). This is how the jQuery code for reading the JSON file looks: https://codepen.io/mslilafowler/pen/xMjZmo?editors=0012

To summarize, the function is trying to check if the file has changed at all, and if the file changed, check if there's any notifications for the current user, and if there are, check if they are new (i.e. within the past 60 seconds, to be consistent). If all these conditions are met, then count the number of new notifications, and then print out the new messages (for testing purposes everything is done in the console).

I've done all this in theory, and have worked with parsing MySQL data into JSON format before, so that's well and good, however I'm faced with a couple issues:

a) This cannot work in Real Time as it is. I searched the entire web on synchronizing MySQL and JavaScript date-times-minus-60-seconds, but I finally reached the burnout stage because

b) PHP is asynchronous, tried using a mixture of Ajax and setInterval to get the actual current real time without page refresh. And this is causing my code to break, since it's checking if there are new notifications within the last 60 seconds, and if the user did not refresh the browser for many minutes, then the current PHP time is the same since the page was initiated, and then the code will reflect the old notifications as 'new'.

c) JavaScript's datetime is so different to MySQL's that I need to use an alternative library like mentions.js just to compare it without the timezones breaking up

d) All of this needs to be done without a page refresh

e) I looked into Websockets, Polling, and Long Polling, but would really prefer if this could be done with javascript/JSON, PHP and MySQL alone.

So I'm nearly there in creating a notification system, except for the mixup of times.

Firstly, each language has it's own time format and timezone, and secondly, the more accurate of the languages is asynchronous, which means that although PHP is more accurate, I can't get the current PHP time without refreshing the page every 1 second.

I feel like the only real solution is to get the returned result from an Ajax call inside a JavaScript setInterval function, something like setInterval(function(){ajax-get-PHP-current-time}, 1000), but my attempts failed hopelessly.

This question does not require opinionated answers, I just need advice on whether this method is okay, and a suggestion on how to synchronize the times between MySQL data, PHP, and JavaScript, without page refresh, in real time so that the old notifications don't get added into the new-within-60-seconds notifications.

Comment: could you please provide a minimal reproduction of your problem? This text is way too long....but i can say that you will need to poll / make use of websockets to achieve something like a notification system

Comment: @messerbill The whole reason for the question is because I'm trying to find a workaround, without using Websockets. The long text is to explain why and how I want to achieve this, otherwise it would be downvoted for 'unclarity'.

Comment: There seem to be a number of problems here. First, PHP isn't async out of the box, you have to use additional libs / exts and write your code to use them. Second, not sure what you mean saying that async languages are "more accurate". Third, languages generally have / know about UTC, so timezone differences can be mitigated. Fourth, why no websockets when it will do what you want. You can also use them with PHP with a bit of work. etc etc. There are various more I could mention. It reads like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks for reading. Between JavaScript and PHP, Php's timestamp is much more accurate that JS mainly because I wouldn't want to handle the timestamp on the client's computer (they could set their date to the past/future). Second, aside from timezone differences, I can't find a way to get the current time in PHP without page refresh, because doing calculations by comparing MySQL and JS is a lot clunkier than doing the calculations by comparing MySQL and PHP. E.g. How can i compare the MySQL timestamp and PHP current time-60 (seconds) , and call the result every 1 second from JS?

Comment: What I would do is give each Notification a unique ID, and then have an AJax request that could ask for all messages since..  No need to worry about date times difference then..

Comment: That^^. The client shouldn't be caring what the server time is. Honestly, I think you need to start your approach over. You want it to be as close to real time as possible, but your points 2 and 3 make it possible that somebody has to wait 2 minutes before getting a notification.Is a JSON file even needed / warranted?

Comment: @Keith That's a brilliant suggestion! It could be easy enough to use MySQL's auto_increment value to fetch results greater than the last recorded ID...Thanx, man,  this solves the entire thing :-)